# Number filter on input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble getting a filter to work on a number/text input.

```
<input type="number" class="text-center" ng-model="redeem.redemption.Amount | number: 2">
```

This throws an error: Expression 'redeem.redemption.Amount | number' is non-assignable
If I remove the filter, it works.  I tried applying the same filter to the angular input demos and it works fine (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number).  Only difference I can see is I am binding to a an object on the scope and not a value directly.  Is there something easy I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that what you are trying to do is to display the "formated value" of what they enter?

Then just remove the filter from the `ng-model` and in your controller `watch` the `redeem.redemption.Amount` and format it when the `watch` gets triggered. you will also need to set a `timeout` in order to allow the user to type, otherwise every time that the user hits a number the `watch` will try to format the number and the user won't be able to type anything.

The code that you have posted will never work because `ng-model` establishes a 2 way data binding with the property of the scope that you indicate, that's why you can not set filters there, it will only accept a property of the scope, that will be updated and from where it will read the value when it changes. The `filter` is a function with one input and retrieves a different output, think about it, if you set the filter, then Angularjs won't know where it has to set the changes of of the input.

Something like this:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$filter,$timeout) {
  $scope.testValue = "0.00";      
  var myTimeout;
  $scope.$watch('testValue', function (newVal, oldVal) {
      if (myTimeout) $timeout.cancel(myTimeout);    
      myTimeout = $timeout(function() {
          if($filter('number')(oldVal, 2)!=newVal)
            $scope.testValue = $filter('number')($scope.testValue, 2);
      }, 500);
  });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/WHhWKdynw0nA4rYoy6ma?p=preview

Try tweaking the delay for the timeout, right now its been set to 500ms.

Comment: Yeah, I want to make sure the value stays a 2 decimal number.  I know I can use a directive or setup a watch, but I don't understand why it would work in the filter example but not in my code.

Comment: That makes sense...but see the example I put in the comment on Mukund's answer, why does that work then?

Comment: Still doesn't explain this, but I'll give you answer since your explanation is good: http://plnkr.co/edit/g0BH6vvTpP9nFDRDyfMx?p=preview

Comment: The explanation for that is simple: do you notice that when you try to edit the field the cursor moves to the end? The reason is that as the user is trying to make updates the filter gets executed and then it overrides the field, making it impossible for the user to make any changes.

Comment: True, but I get an error thrown as it tries to render the page, I can't even get the page to open.  Thanks for the explanations

Answer (score 1):

you cant put filter in ng-model directive.you can do it controller using this:

```
redeem.redemption.Amount=redeem.redemption.Amount.toFixed(2);
```

or you can use jquery to prevent keypress two digits after a decimal number like this:

```
$('.decimal').keypress(function (e) {
        var character = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
        var newValue = this.value + character;
        if (isNaN(newValue) || parseFloat(newValue) * 100 % 1 > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

<input type="number" id="decimal" class="text-center" ng-model="redeem.redemption.Amount | number:">
```

Comment: You can though, only thing I changed from the angular documentation was to add the filter to the ng-model of the input exactly the way I tried to use it in my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/g0BH6vvTpP9nFDRDyfMx?p=preview